# empty value in foreach loop - TCL - unix script

Tags: shell, unix, foreach, tcl

I am getting empty values for the variable $tclItem in the below script in foreach loop even though the list contains values.

Could you please check and see what am i missing?

```
FTP_USER="xxxxx"
FTP_SERVER="xxxxx"
FTP_PWD="xxxx"
FTP_DROP_DIR="DROP/Archive"
LOGFILE="\tmp\log.txt"

FILES_TO_ARCHIVE="$(cat $LOGFILE | grep '.txt' | awk ' !/Fetching/' | tr -d '\r') "
echo "Files to Archive..."
echo ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"
echo $FILES_TO_ARCHIVE
echo ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"


expect <<END 
 spawn sftp $FTP_USER@$FTP_SERVER
 expect "*password: " 
 send "$FTP_PWD\r";
 expect "sftp> "

foreach tclItem {$FILES_TO_ARCHIVE } {
 #puts $tclItem
 send "ls $FTP_DROP_DIR/$tclItem\r"
 expect "sftp> "
};
 send "quit\r"
END
```

and here is the output that i am receiving.

```
Files to Archive.....
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt test4.txt
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

spawn sftp abcdef@sftp.server.com
abcdef@sftp's password:
sftp> ls DROP/Archive/
sftp> ls DROP/Archive/
sftp> ls DROP/Archive/
sftp> ls DROP/Archive/
sftp> invalid command name "test2.txt"
    while executing
"test2.txt"
```

Comment: In general, it's innately buggy to store lists of filenames in a line-oriented format, since filenames on UNIX are allowed to contain newlines (and spaces, and quotes, and other syntactically-sensitive content) themselves.

Comment: Have you considered using a SFTP client built with scripting support, like `lftp`? Or the Python paramiko library's `sftp` tooling will similarly be a better tool for the job than expect+sftp.

Comment: To be clear about *why* this behaves as it does -- variable expansions in a heredoc happen **once**, when the heredoc is generated, which is *before* `expect` is invoked. So by the time the `foreach tclItem` is run by `expect`, `$tclItem` was already replaced with an empty value by the shell interpreter at heredoc evaluation time.

Comment: Anyhow, using a heredoc to generate code with values that haven't been reviewed by a human is **always** a bad idea. Someone submits a file with a name that runs an arbitrary command when interpreted by expect, and next thing you know you're running code of their choice -- downloading a rootkit, opening a reverse shell, etc.

Comment: before the foreach loop, add `puts [list $FILES_TO_ARCHIVE]` -- what is the output?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy unfortunatley, i have to work with the resources that i have got since we do not have permissions to install any more libraries or clients on the server. I understand this might be buggy but i am limited to sftp client. All i am trying to do is move the files from one folder to another on the remote SFTP server.

Comment: @glennjackman I am ending up with invalid command even though i can see hte values in the error. here is the output. ` sftp> invalid command name "test2.txt" while executing "test2.txt" invoked from within "puts [list test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt test4.txt ]" `

Comment: so, the approach I would generally suggest here is *not* to use string substitution to pass your variables from bash to expect, but instead to export them to the environment in bash, and then read them from the environment in TCL. If you change from `<<END` to `<<'END'`, that'll cause bash to stop modifying your code before the expect interpreter sees it, which prevents the potential security issues I discussed above; at that point, it's a matter of figuring out how to read environment variables from TCL, which is outside of my wheelhouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using string substitution to inject data into code (a practice fraught with security concerns), pass your variables from `bash` to `expect` through the environment.

```
# Environment variables should be lowercase except for special/reserved names meaningful
# to the operating system; http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

ftp_user="xxxxx"
ftp_server="xxxxx"
ftp_pwd="xxxx"
ftp_drop_dir="DROP/Archive"
logfile="/tmp/log.txt"
files_to_archive="$(awk '/[.]txt/ && !/Fetching/' <"$logfile" | tr -d '\r')"

export ftp_user ftp_server ftp_pwd ftp_drop_dir files_to_archive

expect <<'END'
 spawn sftp $env(ftp_user)@$env(ftp_server)
 expect "*password: " 
 send "$env(ftp_pwd)\r";
 expect "sftp> "

 set fileList [split $env(files_to_archive) "\n"]

 foreach tclItem $fileList {
   send "ls $env(ftp_drop_dir)/$tclItem\r"
   expect "sftp> "
 };
 send "quit\r"
END
```

Note:

- Using `export` causes shell variables to be available as environment variables in subprocesses. In expect, `$env(foo)` lets one read the environment variable `foo`.
- Using `<<'EOF'` instead of `<<EOF` causes bash to pass the code to `expect` *exactly* as it is, without changes. (Thus, `$tclItem` remains `$tclItem`, instead of being replaced with an empty string before `expect` even starts).

Comment: Even environment variables are imperfect; files and pipes are the best methods, both in terms of security and in terms of the handling of unusual characters. (They're totally the only safe way to move binary data around.) Lots of languages are good at reading and writing files…

Comment: @DonalFellows, I'd appreciate elucidation of your arguments against use of environment variables. Certainly, they were readable by other users in some older operating systems, but I'm unaware of any OS generally considered to be well-maintained and reasonably secure where that's the case today.

Comment: @DonalFellows, ...the other thing that strikes me as a reasonable objection is that environment variables can't contain NULs, so they can't be used to represent all possible filename lists without encoding or escaping steps -- but the OP is extracting their names from a newline-delimited file, so the names by definition can't contain newline literals, making the current newline-based splitting adequate to set of possible inputs here. This code should handle names with all possible non-newline characters correctly.